# Regex for any number followed by space and then a string with spaces

Tags: php, regex

i've tried a lot to find a way to split a string into an array and i found that regex can help me. What is most near the result i need is this regex:  `\d+^[ a-zA-Z]`, but it is incomplete.

My string is something like that:

```
$str = '12 Cheeseburger bacon 2 Chips 3 Coke'
```

and the result i need is an array containing this result:

```
[0] = 12 Cheeseburger bacon
[1] = 2 Chips
[2] = 3 Coke
```

Thank you all for helping

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share the code you are using, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern `\d+^[ a-zA-Z]` matches 1+ digits and then asserts the start of the string using `^` which is not correct. Then it matches a single char out of `[ a-zA-Z]`

You can get the 3 results with matching digits and matching chars a-zA-Z after it where a space is preceded in the repetition.

```
\b\d+(?:\h+[A-Za-z]+)+\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\h+[A-Za-z]+` Match 1+ spaces and 1+ times any of the ranges A-Za-z
- `)+` Repeat 1+ times
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gfanvd/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/89f1W)

```
$re = '/\b\d+(?:\h+[A-Za-z]+)+\b/';
$str = '12 Cheeseburger bacon 2 Chips 3 Coke';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12 Cheeseburger bacon
    [1] => 2 Chips
    [2] => 3 Coke
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_split`:

```php
preg_split('~\s+(?=\d)~', $s)
```

This regex matches one or more whitespace chars before a digit. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QiBTZE/1).

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/8vVPo):

```php
$s = '12 Cheeseburger bacon 2 Chips 3 Coke';
print_r(preg_split('~\s+(?=\d)~', $s));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12 Cheeseburger bacon
    [1] => 2 Chips
    [2] => 3 Coke
)
```

Comment: This solution is much simpler.